# Where I can find a list of certified software / hardware RNGs compliant to NIST SP 800-22?

Tags: rsa, random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, nist, fips-140

I need to use NIST SP 800-22 approved software / hardware to generate RSA key pair.

Where I can find a list of certified software / hardware RNGs compliant to NIST SP 800-22?

And how is the SP 800-22 related to FIPS 186-x? If I generate RSA key pair with approved software compliant to FIPS 186-x, does it mean that it is also compliant to SP 800-22?

Comment: According to [this page](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/random_number.html#Approved%20Algorithms), NIST certifies four DRBG *techniques*, and no NRBGs. It doesn't seem that they've explicitly certified any implementation.

Comment: So how to comply with the following requirement: An approved random number generator that has been certified by an independent laboratory to comply with NIST SP800-22, in connection with RSA key generation?

Comment: I would imagine that you'd need to get your implementation certified, in situ within your product.

Comment: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the document at NIST site pointing to the document (800-22-rev 1a ) updated on April 2010  (http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-22-rev1a/SP800-22rev1a.pdf).

The list of special published (SP) documents are available at (http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsSPs.html)

It involves some reading, but should get your answers. Since it will keep changing wouldn't paste an answer here.